# Как удалить первые и  последние 5 строк в цикле

Tags: delphi

На форме есть memo в нём текст, нужно удалить из него первые 5 строк и последние 5 строк
как лучше сделать в цикле или без него?

Comment: @Кривошея, что за идиотизм? Кстати, фамилия прикольная =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если по 5, а если надо по 125 ? Конечно, проще сделать цикл

```
for i:=0 to 4 do
begin
  Memo1.Lines.Delete(0);
  Memo1.Lines.Delete(Memo1.Lines.Count-1);
end;
```

Вместо

```
Memo1.Lines.Delete(0);
Memo1.Lines.Delete(0);
Memo1.Lines.Delete(0);
Memo1.Lines.Delete(0);
Memo1.Lines.Delete(0);
Memo1.Lines.Delete(Memo1.Lines.Count-1);
Memo1.Lines.Delete(Memo1.Lines.Count-1);
Memo1.Lines.Delete(Memo1.Lines.Count-1);
Memo1.Lines.Delete(Memo1.Lines.Count-1);
Memo1.Lines.Delete(Memo1.Lines.Count-1);
```

Answer (score 2):

Если ваша зарплата зависит от количества написанных строк кода - конечно же циклы использовать будет невыгодно, т.к. за 2×5 строк китайского кода заплатят в 2,5 раза больше, чем за 2×2 нормального :-)